# Algorithm. Input: pointers to k unsorted arrays of different lengths. Needed output: k sorted arrays

Tags: algorithms, counting

$k = \Theta(n)$

The arrays consist only natural numbers $1$ to $n$

The sum of the length of all arrays = $\Theta(n)$

It should return the $k$ original arrays, each sorted on its own.

The running time should be at worst $\Theta(n)$.
How is it even possible? There's something I must be missing because I have no idea how to approach this.
The data I gave you is all the given data. Any ideas?

Using counting sort on each array won't work, for it will be $\Theta(n^2)$, but maybe a different approach using this method?

Comment: Just for iterating over all arrays you need $\theta(n^2)$ operations, are you sure about your text ?

Comment: sorry I edit it, the change is "The sum of the length of all arrays = θ(n)
"

Comment: No (explicit/$\omicron(n)$) limit on space? How is the problem/solution different from handling a single such array?

Comment: Cheeky (practical but impermissible) non-answer: radix sort all of the arrays.

Comment: @greybeard There's no space limit to this question. the difference is you need to sort each array on its own, every element should stay at his original array.

Comment: @Veedrac I didn't understand how it solves the problem? it won't leave the element in their original array if I get you right.

Comment: I missed $k = \Theta(n)$ - which means the length of each array is $\Theta(1)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve the issue by using some pointers. First, run counting sort algorithm on all arrays in $\Theta(n)$ (suppose all of them are in a set). In the meanwhile, when running the algorithm, set a pointer for each number of each array  to the sorted index of that number.

Using this data structure, you will have $k$ sorted arrays at the end.

Comment: tnx, sorry but I didn't quite understand the part when you set pointers. can you elaborate? you point each number to its index in the counter?

Comment: @MatanyaP Yes. Indeed, you can see all these arrays as a single array. Then sort them using counting sort algorithm. When you run the algorithm, set a pointer from each element of each array to its index in that universal sorting. In this way, you have sorted the sub arrays.

Comment: Note that you need multiple counts per bucket, and to avoid allocating it all in advance that means you probably want to make each bucket a dynamically-sized hash map. Not all that cheap on real hardware ;).